# Dynamic routing using flask and Python not working

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm struggling with setting up dynamic routing using flask (sqlalchemy) and Python. When I test the code, the url renders properly. However, the link renders the layout template, but not the book extension.

I've been staring at the code, and I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Can anyone spot what I've done wrong?

Here is the html with the dynamic link:

```
{% for book in books %}
        <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="{{ url_for('book', book_id=book.book_id) }}">
                    {{ book.isbn }}
              </a>
            </td>
            <td>{{ book.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ book.author }}</td>
            <td>{{ book.year }}</td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the book.html template extension html. The "Book Details" static content is not rendering:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Book Details
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Book Details</h1>

    <ul>
        <li>ISBN: {{ book.isbn }}</li>
        <li>Title: {{ book.title }}</li>
        <li>Author: {{ book.author }}</li>
        <li>Publication Year: {{ book.year }}</li>
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

And finally, the application.py route:

```
@app.route("/results/<int:book_id>")
def book(book_id):
    """Lists details about a single book."""

    # Look up book in the database
    book = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_id = :book_id", {"book_id": book_id}).fetchone()

    return render_template("book.html", book=book)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem is in your first line:**
You don't have any variable called books, passed into your html
**Try**
for fo in book

(I wanted to add this as comment but I couldn't)

Comment: books is passed into the html here: {% for book in books %} in the first code snippet. This part of the code renders correctly

Comment: check if  index/results/(anybookidhere) gives any webpage, i think problem is in your links, they are not properly linking to the book function you defined under /results/<bookid> part

Comment: there was a problem with the layout template. thanks for taking a look